# Replacing values in an object

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{id: 1, cells: ["Ashar", 68345, 14, 66666, "Retail", 1, ""]}
```

And I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
 {id: 1, cells: ["Ashar", 68345, 14, 46100, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 2, cells: ["Ashar", 300881, 14, 37000, "Retail", 3, 3]}, 
 {id: 3, cells: ["Rob", 94448, 17, 11395, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 4, cells: ["Shahab", 19023870, 219, 12500, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 5, cells: ["David", 29008000, 229, 12500, "Retail", 5, 26]}
]
```

What I am trying to do is take the id of the first object and use it to search through the array to find the matching id and then replace the value of `cells` with the value from the first object.

Any help with figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
var temp = {id: 1, cells: ["Ashar", 68345, 14, 66666, "Retail", 1, ""]};

var arr=[
 {id: 1, cells: ["Ashar", 68345, 14, 46100, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 2, cells: ["Ashar", 300881, 14, 37000, "Retail", 3, 3]}, 
 {id: 3, cells: ["Rob", 94448, 17, 11395, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 4, cells: ["Shahab", 19023870, 219, 12500, "Retail", 1, ""]}, 
 {id: 5, cells: ["David", 29008000, 229, 12500, "Retail", 5, 26]}
];    
arr.forEach(function(value,key){
    if(value.id == temp.id) {
           value.cells=temp.cells;
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help!